# Чем вызвана ошибка UnityEditor.AssetDatabase:Refresh()?

Tags: c#, unity3d, assets

Столкнулся с такой ошибкой:

> Assets/AAA/Ander/Level_s/Part_2(new)/Level_2_2. is not a valid asset
>   file name. Please make sure there are no slashes or other unallowed
>   characters in the file name. The file will be ignored.

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Ошибка появляется в режиме редактирвания, когда переключаюсь между сценами. Все буквы в проекте - латиница. Каталог Level_2_2 сгенерирован самой Unity для хранения лайтмапов. В этом каталоге я так же храню другие данные сцены.

При двойном клике по этой ошибке ничего не происходит.

Так же появляется такая ошибка:

> Assets/AAA/Ander/Level_s/Part_2(new)/Level_2_2. is not a valid asset
>   file name. Please make sure there are no slashes or other unallowed
>   characters in the file name. The file will be ignored.
>   UnityEditor.AssetDatabase:Refresh()
>   Bridge_Corrector_Abstract:SaveMeshAsAsset() (at
>   Assets/Units/Rooms/Part_2/Bridge/Scripts/Bridge_Corrector_Abstract.cs:58)
>   Bridge_Corrector_Abstract_Editor:OnInspectorGUI() (at
>   Assets/Units/Rooms/Part_2/Bridge/Editor/Bridge_Corrector_Abstract_Editor.cs:16)
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

В скрипте эта ошибка вызвана методом сохранения меша в ассет:

> public void SaveMeshAsAsset () {
>
> ```
>     string path = getAssetPath ();
>
>     if (Directory.Exists ( path ) == false)
>         Directory.CreateDirectory ( path );
>
>     string assetName = path + getAssetName ();
>     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty ( assetName )) {
>
>         AssetDatabase.CreateAsset ( GetComponent<MeshFilter> ().sharedMesh, assetName );// OR REWRITE ASSET
>         AssetDatabase.Refresh ();//<<<< Здесь ошибка, стока 58
>         EditorGUIUtility.PingObject ( AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath ( assetName, typeof ( Object ) ) );
>     }
> }
> ```

Меш сохраняется, путь верный, путь не содержит двойных слешей, всяких символов типа "?,.*%". Единственно что, assetName содеожит еще и имя файла, в итоге получается что-то типа: path/fileName.asset

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: написано же `Assets/AAA/Ander/Level_s/Part_2(new)/Level_2_2. is not a valid asset file name`. Так может, ему скобочки не нравятся или слеши?

Comment: Этот путь он мне сам выдал: string path = EditorSceneManager.GetActiveScene ().path; Слеши еще не пробовал инвертировать в другую сторону.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity умеет приподносить сюрпризы.

В процессе работы я случайно создал папку с именем "Level_2_2." и работал в ней.
Позже заметил ошибку и исключил точку из названий создаваемых папок.

В редакторе Unity есть подобие проводника, которое отображает все файлы и дерево каталогов. Так вот, как оказалось, кастомный проводник Unity не отображал папку "Level_2_2." С одной стороны я искал эту папку в кастомном проводнике и не находил, с другой стороны Unity постоянно сетовал на какую-то несуществующую папку.

Проводник операционки показывает эту папку. Удаление папки устранило ошибку.

Comment: Ты ввёл в название папки или файла недопустимый знак. Поэтому Unity игнорировало эту папку.